# how do you validate sub digit values with numbers allowing .5 or .0 without an input mask?

Tags: validation, ms-access, input, ms-access-2010, formulas

My clients are getting frustrated at typing in 000.5 or 001.0 in a number of days field due to being forced to use an input mask to prevent invalid values.

I have managed to sort out validation for a range of numerical values 180.0 - 0.5 allowing only half or whole values to be entered.  An example of values not allowed:-

```
1.2
1.02
1.222  
0.01
0.001
181.0   <-- above the range
```

The only values allowed are:-

```
0.5  - 180.0
```

but this is only possible with an input mask.  Using the formulae :-

```
 (([NoOfDays]*10) Mod 5)=0 And <=180 And >=0.5
```

and an input mask of 000.0 or 009.0  you can prevent sub decimal values but without it, it appears to be not possible with this formulae.

Without the input mask customers can enter:- 1.05, 2.51   etc.

Is there a formulae for solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a *Validation Rule* in table design for a field named *NoOfDays*, I think this does what you want:

```vb
(Int([NoOfDays]) Or Int([NoOfDays])+0.5) And Between 0.5 And 180
```

Comment: Wow,  this really works, I have been banging my head trying to solve it.  At least I dont have to force data values and can properly validate now.  Thanks a million. :)